# How to Delete Call Log

Tags: android, calllog

Can any one please tell me how to delete call log from android phone,

I am using following line of code

```
 getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
```

but, this is not working for me I want to delete whole call log history.

Answer (score 4):

Following code work for me..

```
private void deleteNumber() {
                try {
                    String strNumberOne[] = { "00577698160" };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ? ", strNumberOne, "");
                    boolean bol = cursor.moveToFirst();
                    if (bol) {
                        do {
                            int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));
                            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.print("Exception here ");
                }
            }
```

Edit:
 following code is also work for me In API 23

make sure u have following permission in manifast.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

for Deleting Calllogs for particular number try this way:

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String number) {   
    String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);
    }  
}
```

Comment: In Marshmallow you need user permission to do Cursor

Comment: ya i have a problem with marshmallown and also i am using 23 api

Comment: @Asmi yeah i have tried it all but it ois not working for me i don't know where i am wrong i am using the above code but when i return to the phone call log the value is still there no change :(

Comment: @Ankita <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" /> this two permission is must

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is working perfectly for me in android Lollipop :)

```
private void deleteCall(String number) {
    Uri CALLLOG_URI = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"); 
    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(CALLLOG_URI, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER +"=?",new String[]{number});
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Call Log Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.I am deleting call log by its log id please check below code for it.

```
private void deleteCall(String idd) {

    context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, CallLog.Calls._ID + " = ? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(idd)});

}
```